# Using Sentiment Analysis to Detect Contradictory Arguments?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, nlp, text-processing, sentiment-analysis

I don't have much background in sentiment analysis or natural language processing at all, but I have been reading a bit about it in my spare time.  I would like to conduct and experiment to analyze forum threads/comments such as reddit, digg, blogs, etc.  I'm particularity interested in doing something like counting the number of for, against, and neutral comments for threads of heated religious and political debates.  Here's what I am thinking.

1) Find a thread that the original poster has defined a touchy political or religious topic.

2) For each comment categorize it as supporting the original poster or otherwise taking a contradicting or neutral stance.

3) Compare various mediums with the numbers of for or against arguments to determine what platforms are good "debate platforms" (i.e. balanced argument counts).

One big problem that I'm anticipating is that heated topics will invoke strong reactions from both supporting and contradicting parties so a simple happy/sad sentiment analysis won't cut it.  I'm just sort of interested in this project for my own curiosities, so if anyone knows of similar research or utilities to conduct this experiment I'd be interested to hear more.

Can someone recommend a good sentiment analysis, word dictionary, training set, etc. for this task?

Comment: Interesting problem, but way to broad for SO; you should start by gathering actual data and investigating it for patterns. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) [or even better: use [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) as tokens to the bag]

The approach is basically:

1. Classify a set of examples, let your algorithm extract the relevant
   words from the classified examples.
2. When a new comment is given, extract the relevant words, and use
   [k-nearest neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) to decide if the new comment is a
   pro/against/neutral.

Also, you might want to have a look on [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about building the wordlist from the training set like that.  And the nice thing about religious and political debates is there are more than enough examples that can be used for training sets :P

Comment: Although I like this idea, I am not sure how well it would work. Each comment does not always refer to the original post but also to other comments.

Comment: BOW with k-NN works for simple document classification, but I feel it's way underpowered for this task. -1.

Comment: @larsmans: Do you have experimental information showing it is not enough? I know it got me a high place in a competition in UNI for determining recommendation of comments/tweets: pro or against in a project I did last year. This is a valid suggestion [IMO] - and the OP should for the very least take it as a baseline for more advanced solutions while experimenting

Comment: I undid my -1 because it was a bit too harsh; I re-read the question and it might get the OP a reasonable baseline.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO this is not possible without running into semantics. Consider the sentence:

> Unlike many others, I am not against the abolishment of capital punishment.

Your AI may need to recognise idiomatic subfrases like "not against", or other "not ..." snippets. This is not impossible ;-)

An additional problem is, that "not" is more or less a stopword, its rank will probably be in the top-100, causing a low entropy (though it has a high "semantic" value to every sentence where it is unsed). Also note that omitting "the abolishment of", will cause the "polarity" of the sentence to flip as well.

Comment: Good point.  Do you know of any toolkits / word lists that would address that problem?  I'm sure it has been considered and approached somewhere before.

Comment: I guess `Watson` has tackled the problem in some way ... But it comes close to natural language *parsing* , including the semantics. When I reshaped Megahal (a Markovian chatbot) into Wakkerbot (a Markovian shoutbot), I had to remove the functions that dealt with "finding the opposites"; a hardcoded list of pairs of words. (Megahal tried to oppose his conversation partner). Wakkerbot tends to more or less approach the average Joe. That's why "Hubert Both" stayed unnoticed for about 5 months. The keyword / buzzword detection is still crucial.

Comment: Bad example; if we assume a simple BOW classifier and we assume that "not" will be considered a stopword (I'm not sure what entropy has to do with this), then the terms "against" and "abolishment" will likely cause a "negative" classification.

Comment: Good example. I could just add another "inverting" word: "the taboo on abolishment". "Not" being a stopword is a matter of definition. In a statistical sense all high-frequency words are stopwords. In a semantic sense they are not.

Comment: I disagree. The idea behind [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) and Machine Learning based algorithms is probabalistic: If the double negation is common to be pro - then most likely it is also common in the training set and will be classified as pro, and the algorithm will "catch" it as pro. If it is uncommon - the algorithm will miss it indeed, but this is uncommon, so we are not mistaking too often about it. AI  algorithms usually don't try to get 100% accurate, they just want to get it "good enough".

Comment: Not all IR and ML is probabilistic. But my point is that the example shows a triple negation with two negative words in it.